# I can't connect internet emulator with android 4.0

Tags: android, sql-server, android-emulator

I can't connect to the internet on a emulator (api14) with android 4.0.
But in android2.2 emulator I can.

How can I connect to the internet on android 4.0 emulator?

My program connects to sqlserver using the 2.2 emulator but he can't connect using 4.0.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.bangkok.kohfood"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".KohFoodActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   </application>
</manifest>

Connection conn = null;
String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.1.11:1433/";
String dbName = "koh;Instance=MSSQLSERVER;";
String userName = "bit"; 
String password = "1234";
String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
  Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
```

Comment: jtds 1.2.5 support android4.0 ?

Comment: Have you used AsyncTask? If you have used please update your post with that code.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see Internet indicator icon at top of screen? if no, go to settings and make sure Wi-Fi is set to ON.

Comment: jtds 1.2.5 support android4.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Android 4, apps aren't allowed anymore to do network communication in the main (=UI) thread. Without seeing your code I can't say for sure, but could this be your problem?

To test this, you should move your network communication to a background thread and see if it works.

Comment: This code doesn't show whether it runs in the main thread or in a background thread.